# Wpf panel layout - one child, several positions

Tags: wpf, layout, panel, instance

I am working on a WPF panel derivative with custom layout logic and sometimes it might be that component should be visible in two places, when following that layouting logic. Both instances of the same component will be partially cropped. Is it possible to do this - lay out a child component in two different places during the arrange pass?

Comment: I'm quite certain this isn't possible, you'll have to have 2 different components that act similar (and can be bound to the same backing objects), but I don't think they can actually be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the panels behaviors are for arrange items in a view, and not for copy the items. I think this is not possible. If you copy a visual element then it will not be the same. If you want get this effect you may use a `VisualBrush` and paint  some region with that, and set to the brush the control that you may want to copy. Using `VisualBursh` you will see a control copy, but you will not be able to modify it. The other way is using a custom control for making this effect. Other way could be using two different custom panels, both with the same items source (in the case that be the `ItemsPanel` for some collection).

Hope this answer helps to you...

Comment: The VisualBrush method is the correct way to accomplish this. A duplicate panel would create unwanted overhead. Good answer, Raul!

Comment: Thanks, I might go with this as it seems as the best way to accomplish what I want to.